# Can we run parallel job and server job in a sequence?

Tags: datastage

Can we run parallel job and server job in a sequence? Like putting parallel job in one sequence and server job in other sequence and later put them in parent sequence and run. Is it possible?

Comment: Does it works for you?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to add a Job Activity in the sequence job, and select the parallel or server job, that you want to invocate, in the "Job name" option.

Note: If the invoked job have parameters, in the Job Activity properties you could set it.

Edit: Images

[image]

[image]

Images from DataStage 9.1.2

Comment: @S.Jain Please accept the answer and if you liked it, vote up too. Thanks